# How do I efficiently compute the largest prime factor of really large numbers?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I am trying to perform the following operation for values n > 74: 
`max(factor(sym(n)^n + (sym(1-n))^(n-1)))`

This finds the largest prime factor of the operation: `sym(n)^n + (sym(1-n))^(n-1)`.
Currently, computing the largest prime factor takes quite a bit of time for values n > 74 (the ones I need to find), and I am wondering if there's a faster way to do this in MATLAB. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you use `sym`? Why do you use MATLAB? I'm just trying to figure out if you've considered any other (and possibly more appropriate) tools for this job.

Comment: @Dev-iL: The numbers are far beyond the limits of uint64, at least in MATLAB sym or vpa is the only option.

Comment: @Dev-iL: As Daniel said, these are really large numbers I’m dealing with. What other tool could I use to Quickly compute the largest prime factor of numbers of this many digits?

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel, it might be an option to use the data from some freely available prime databases...

Comment: @Patrick Happel: no such thing exists for the numbers I am working with.

Comment: If you work with such numbers, it sounds true that C/C++ will be the tool for efficiency, and not Matlab

Comment: I am not sure if MATLAB is actually the problem here. Sure the symbolic math toolbox has a large overhead per operation, but we are talking about a few operations here until everything is passed to efficient implementations.